# 7- Field collection fields are not showing in registration profile

Tags: users, entities

I'm trying to create a registration profile using `Profile 2`, in this profile most of all fields are `field collections`. The problem is, when I try to create account for this profile, none of them are showing up in the form.

I've tried by setting the permissions with [field permission module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions), But still not working.

See the snapshot.

[image: Profile fields without contents]

Please anyone tell me how can I make these fields to show up in the form.

Comment: Have you write any custom module to alter your form? May be issue because of that.

Comment: @SumitMadan there is a custom module. But that is not affecting here. I've already checked that by disabling the module.

Comment: I have installed both profile 2 (dev version) and field_collection, and it is working fine (used main profile type). The field_collection fields show up in the account registration process, both with admin creating the user, and anonymous creating the account. Suggest you create a new install of Drupal and test it there, which is in any case always a good practice when hunting down issues.

Comment: @J.Reynolds Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try your way.